# Mocking asynchronous requests within react's getInitialState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

When i created this question, my doubt was about how would i be able to test an asynchronous request utilizing mocha/enzyme/chai/sinon.
I am sure that there are different ways, but a possible one is to mock it with a handmade function that returns the appropriate values (check the answer for details).
My getInitialState method is this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var me = this;
    var documentData = null;
    var promise = me.getDocuments();

    promise.then(function(value) {
        var documents = value.map(function(obj) {
            return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
                return obj[key];
            });
        });

        documentData = documents;
    });

    return ({
        cd: false
    });
},
```

And the getDocuments() function that returns a promise is this:

```
getDocuments: function() {
    var deferred = when.defer();

    Collection.fetch({cd: workspaceInfo.getCD()}).then(
        function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        deferred.reject
    );

    return deferred.promise;
},
```

How can i successfuly test it? 
Would i have to mock the getInitialState method itself? (is that even possible)
Or just the getDocuments function with some predictable return values?
Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by requiring the Collection (which is a rest API that brings some values from a database)

```
var Collection = require("path/to/my/collection/Collection");
```

Afterwards, i use it in my getDefaultProps() method:

```
getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            Collection: new Collection()
        };
    },
```

And this in turn enables me to write tests that initialize a mocked Collection (fileDataResponse is a JSON with some data):

```
var CollectionMock= {
    fetch: () => {
        return {
            then: callback => callback(fileDataResponse)
        };
    }
};
```

And use it in my test afterwards:

```
it("should open the modal without a loaded configuration", function() {
    var instance, wrapper;

    wrapper = mount(
        <DocumentPreview 
        Collection={CollectionMock}/>
    );

    instance = wrapper.component.getInstance();
    instance.openModal();
    expect(wrapper.find('#MockedTest' + 'docOid251085').exists()).to.equal(true);

    wrapper.unmount();
});
```